# Squares numbers into squares

Tags: number-theory

Solve the two related questions below in which lowercase letters are digits in base $10$, $a > 0$ and $N\in\Bbb N$. Find the values of $N$ in $(1)$ and prove or deny $(2):$

$$ (1)\left\{\begin{array}{c}N^2=abcd \\ ab \text{ and } cd \text{ are squares}\end{array}\right.\qquad \qquad (2)\left\{\begin{array}{c}N^2=abcdef \\ \text{Neither }abc \text{ nor } def \text{ can be square}\end{array}\right.$$
[image]
         Knowing that 41 is the only number that answers to the question (1) with four digits in its square, I wondered about the number X of numbers N responding to the question with six, eight ... .., 2n digits in N^2. In short I want to know the number X of solutions of the equation above and to show that there is always solution or find the minimum n such that X = 0. I like this but no problem if you discard it.

Comment: Do $a,b,c,d,e,f$ have to be different?

Comment: Not necessarily. Thanks Ross.(pay attention to question (2); it is not so easy).

Comment: I would've closed this question for being "unclear what you're asking" not for being "off-topic." For one thing, I'm not understanding how these two questions are related besides both being about squares and concatenations of digits. Do $a, b, c, d$ in (1) have to be the same $a, b, c, d$ in (2)? And this might sound like a dumb question, but does $N$ in (1) have to be the same $N$ in (2)?

Comment: I disagree with the closure.  I think it is clear what is requested in 1.  It does look a bit like homework with no effort shown.  I believe 2 has two interpretations, which are in my last comment to Albert's answer, which provides a good one to 1, and covers one case of 2.  I had fun with it.

Comment: Even a moron would say that N is not the same in (1) and (2) but I agree that, in effect, a, b and c could perhaps confuse something. I should have chosen the word “analogous” rather than “related” (I don’t know well English language). The suggested edition has been made with my limits of language but I'm too lazy to read carefully instructions to do it.

Comment: The generalization is then are there squares $N^2$ with an even number $n$ of digits such that $\lfloor \frac {N^2}{10^{n/2}}\rfloor$ and $N^2 \pmod {10^{n/2}}$ are both squares.  We now have the only example for $n=2$ and the only two examples for $n=3$.  I would suggest asking another question along these lines. If you would like to do so, go ahead.  If you would prefer that a  native speaker to do so, ping me and I will.

Comment: Perfect. Do it yourself. Note this poses a Diophantine equation with constraints (more complicated as it grows n) identified in the three integer variables. You are very kind (AS MANY MATHEMATICIANS!).

Comment: There are more than 2 solutions for n = 3 and the problem considers calculate its number X. It is not certain a priori that X is always positive and discovered that such X = 0 (if it exists) there would be very interesting.

Answer (score 3):

$41^2 = 1681$

$16 = 4^2$

$81 = 9^2$

---

$318^2 = 101124$

$\sqrt{101} \approx 10.04$

$\sqrt{124} \approx 11.13$

Comment: What about the number of solutions and the way you have got these examples without calculator? That's we are interested.

Comment: These would be easy to find without a calculator.  There are only two one digit numbers that square to two digit numbers, so only four possibilities to try. As we know $101$ is not a square, neither $8181$ nor $1616$ are candidates.  It turns out $8116$ doesn't work.  For the second, almost any six digit square should provide an example.  That doesn't prove that you can't have $abc$ or $def$ square in any six digit one.

Comment: They say Ramanujan knew abuot $1729$ long before Hardy told him it was uninteresting. I knew about $1681$ long before you posted this question. As for $101124$, I had to search for it and I had help from a calculator: $\sqrt{10^5} \approx 316.2$, so then I did  `Range[316,416]^2` in Wolfram alpha.

Comment: though if you look at the edit history, you'll notice I was confused bay your second quetsion. I first said $380^2$, because I thought $abc$ and $def$ had to be squares as well. When I realized my mistake, that second question seemed much, much easier.

Comment: I don't agree, Albert. Regards.

Comment: I agree, Ross: " almost any six digit square should provide an example." and proving with 683 (no more) numbers you can answer however it is not funny.

Comment: Um, I'm confused now. If you agree that "almost any six digit square should provide an example" how can you disagree that $(2)$ is a much, much easier question?

Comment: I believe question 2 is not clear between "find an N such that $N^2=abcdef$ and neither $abc$ nor $def$ is square, which is what I thought most six digit squares would provide and example of, or "prove or disprove there is no N such that $N2=abcdef$ and at least one of $abc, def$ is square."  In my answer I provide examples that disprove the second, and logic that does not require a calculator to find one.

Answer (score 2):

For 2, it is quite possible for one of $abc$ or $def$ to be square.  It is even possible for both of them to be.  $380^2=144400$ is composed of $144=12^2$ and $400=20^2$  There are many cases where one is a square.  If we are to deny the statement that neither can be a square, one of these is all we need and the square of many multiples of $10$ will be an example:  $320^2=102400$ is the lowest six digit example.  This is easy to find without a calculator.  I don't see how to find the examples with both $abc$ and $def$ squares without a calculator, though if you only want to try multiples of $10$ there are only $68$ to try and you would find $380^2$ and $570^2$ that way.  It's a bit of work but not too much.

Other examples with both squares are $475^2=225625, 506^2=256036,570^2=324900,759^2=576081$  Only $380^2$ and $475^2$ avoid a leading zero in $def$

Comment: Well Ross. Anyway I would like to see a method, a deduction of response. Thank you.

Comment: An example is all that is required to deny the statement.  I did use Excel for the calculation, but figuring out that most multiples of $10$ will make $def$ a square is easy without a calculator.  You just reflect on the fact that squaring $ab0$ will end with the last digit of $b^2$, often $0,1,4,9$ followed by $00$ and you are done

Comment: That is true, an example is all we need. My question was  badly worded.  A manner to see it another way is either with diophantine equations or  school algorithm for extracting the square root.